# What is Chrome's behavior when no Connection header is set for SSL connections?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, connection, keep-alive

My server is not sending back a Connection header for a SSL page and I
am noticing that the connections are getting closed after each use
instead of being kept alive.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-8.1 says:
A significant difference between HTTP/1.1 and earlier versions of
HTTP is that persistent connections are the default behavior of any
HTTP connection. That is, unless otherwise indicated, the client
SHOULD assume that the server will maintain a persistent connection,
even after error responses from the server.

Is this the default behavior for Chrome when it connects through SSL?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome not honoring https in relative URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936209/chrome-not-honoring-https-in-relative-urls)