# Chrome loading script over http on https page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, ssl, https

We have absolute paths in template, i.e.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/media/css/ui.css?v=3" />
```

When I'm trying to open https page - I get following error:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://{{ full_site }}/{{secure_page}}' was loaded over HTTPS, 
but ran insecure content from 'http://{{full_site }}/media/css/ui.css?v=3': 
this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

But path `https://{{full_site }}/media/css/ui.css?v=3` is available...

Tell me, why chrome trying to load content over http on https page? And how to force it to load scripts over https on relative paths?

**UPD** Page loads perfectly in firefox. So this is only chrome issue. All paths are relative.

Comment: What is the absolute URI of the resource?

Comment: This might be helpful to you https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/fix_website_with_mixed_content#How_to_fix_your_website

Comment: Do your CSS `ui.css` has any url property which loads HTTP content ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome not honoring https in relative URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936209/chrome-not-honoring-https-in-relative-urls)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be the reason that your CSS file `ui.css` may be referring to resources (e.g. images) via `background or background-image` property which is loading insecure content (Content from HTTP servers)

If you have resources on your site, use **Relative Protocol Links** like

```
url(//example.com/images/some_image.png)
```

Similarly, update your link to use relative protocol link like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//{{full site}}/media/css/ui.css?v=3" />
```

Comment: In css we have `url` like `background: url("/media/images/lock.png");`... Adding `//{{fullsite}}/` must help? What if we have multidomain application?